# Que tipo de perguntas podem ser aqui feitas?

Tags: debate, suporte, meta

Gostaria de perceber qual a diferença ou as diferenças entre usar o [Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) e [Stack Overflow Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/), tentei ir ao menu de ajuda do *Meta* mas não consegui encontrar nada, sempre que tentava entrar na ajuda ele me enviava para a ajuda do [Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) o *Meta* não tem ajuda?

Que tipo de perguntas consigo e posso fazer no *Meta* que se considerem de qualidade?

Comment: Estão localizadas no site principal, na seção de ajuda Central de ajuda > Nosso modelo > [O que é o "meta"? Como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Stack Overflow em Português Meta é a parte do site onde os usuários **discutem o funcionamento e as políticas do Stack Overflow em Português**, em vez de discutir o programação em si. Um espaço para que as pessoas **perguntem como e por que este site funciona do jeito que funciona**.<sup>[1](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/meta/info)</sup>

---

Um lugar que se pergunta sobre o funcionamento do SO<sup>pt</sup>. Ele é separado das perguntas e respostas principais para reduzir a confusão e oferecer um espaço legítimo para que as pessoas perguntem como e por que este site funciona do jeito que funciona.

O Meta é para:

- fazer perguntas sobre como funciona o site;
- fazer perguntas da comunidade;
- publicar bugs;
- sugerir melhorias;
- propor novos recursos;

---

Para perguntas que fogem do escopo do site principal, ou se você quer fazer uma pergunta mais informal, use o chat: [(Estouro de Pilha - `(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻`)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Já se você quiser fazer uma pergunta mais informal sobre o Meta, use o outro chat: [( Debate da Pilha)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57786/debate-da-pilha).